# ASP.NET Web Api OData v4 - How to reflect decimal scale and precision through $metadata?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2 / OData v4.0 is it possible to define the decimal scale and precision in the $metadata endpoint?

Currently I have defined a PricingModel.cs containing a number of decimal attributes:

```
...
public decimal? PurchasePrice { get; set; }        
public decimal? SellingPrice { get; set; }
...
```

PricingController.cs inheriting from ODataController and a basic Entity Data Model is defined in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    // Model builder
    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<PricingModel>("Pricing");

    // Map route (Default)
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: null,
        model: builder.GetEdmModel());

    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

What is reflected in the $metadata is (missing scale and precision):

```
...    
<Property Name="PurchasePrice" Type="Edm.Decimal"/>
<Property Name="SellingPrice" Type="Edm.Decimal"/>
...
```

The [OData Version 4.0 Common Schema Definition](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part3-csdl-complete.html#_Toc453752531) should allow for the scale and precision to be included in the $metadata.

> **6.2.4 Attribute Scale**
>
> A decimal property MAY define a non-negative integer value or variable for the Scale attribute.
>
> This attribute specifies the maximum number of digits allowed to the right of the decimal point.
>
> The value variable means that the number of digits to the right of the decimal point may vary from zero to the value of the Precision attribute.
>
> An integer value means that the number of digits to the right of the decimal point may vary from zero to the value of the Scale attribute, and the number of digits to the left of the decimal point may vary from one to the value of the Precision attribute minus the value of the Scale attribute. If Precision is equal to Scale, a single zero has to precede the decimal point.
>
> The value of the Scale attribute MUST be less than or equal to the value of the Precision attribute. If no value is specified, the Scale facet defaults to zero.
>
> Note: if the underlying data store allows negative scale, services may use a Precision attribute with the absolute value of the negative scale added to the actual number of significant decimal digits, and client-provided values may have to be rounded before being stored.
>
> Example 9: Precision and Scale facets applied to the Decimal type.
>   Allowed values: 1.23, 0.23, 3.14 and 0.7, not allowed values: 123, 12.3.
>
> `<Property Name="Amount" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="3" Scale="2" />`
>
> Example 10: Precision equals Scale.
>   Allowed values: 0.23, 0,7, not allowed values: 1.23, 1.2.
>
> `<Property Name="Amount" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="2" Scale="2" />`
>
> Example 11: Precision and a variable Scale applied to the Decimal type.
>   Allowed values: 0.123, 1.23, 0.23, 0.7, 123 and 12.3, not allowed would be: 12.34, 1234 and 123.4 due to the limited precision.
>
> `<Property Name="Amount" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="3" Scale="variable" />`

Reading up on [Configure the OData Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) I understand that I probably should modify the Entity Data Model (EDM) through the ODataModelBuilder instance in some way but can't seem to find my way around it.

> An EDM is an abstract model of the data. The EDM is used to create the service metadata document. The ODataConventionModelBuilder class creates an EDM by using default naming conventions. This approach requires the least code. If you want more control over the EDM, you can use the ODataModelBuilder class to create the EDM by adding properties, keys, and navigation properties explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code did the trick, maybe it'll help someone else...

```
...
// Model builder
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<PricingModel>("Pricing");
builder.EntitySet<PricingModel>("Pricing").EntityType.Property(x => x.PurchasePrice).Precision = 19;
builder.EntitySet<PricingModel>("Pricing").EntityType.Property(x => x.PurchasePrice).Scale = 3;
...
```

And this is now what's reflected in $metadata...

```
...
<Property Name="PurchasePrice" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="19" Scale="3"/>
...
```